# How to add month name in different columns with respective records sql?

Tags: sql

```
DECLARE @month INT
SET @month=1

SELECT 

    CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_Id,

    NoOfInv = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month
                        AND DATEPART(yyyy, in_date_issued) = 2014
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),

    MonthTotal = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month 
                           AND DATEPART(yyyy, in_date_issued) = 2014
                          THEN in_total ELSE 0 END),

    Grandtotal = SUM(in_total),

    RemainingAmount = SUM(in_total) - SUM(CASE 
                          WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month 
                          THEN in_total ELSE 0 END)


FROM (SELECT 
          DISTINCT MasterOrderId, cl_Id 
      FROM 
          CLOI_ClientOrderItems) as CLOI_ClientOrderItems 

INNER JOIN 
      IN_Invoices 
ON
      IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
GROUP BY 
  CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
```

I want output like

```
noofinv |amt      |clid       | grandtotal |   jan         |feb     |march  |remainingamt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5       |7.00     |100000_Pri | 245.00     |   0.00        |238.00  |7.00   |238.00
12      |2510.12  |100001_pro | 181110.29  |   138891.92   |9708.25 |510.12 |178600.17
```

Comment: I think you need to use CTEs. Try [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have them in separate columns, this would work

```
select 
Count(IN_Invoices.in_id) NoOfInv,
NoOfInv_jan2014=sum(case when datepart(mm, in_date_issued) = 1 and 
                datepart(yyyy, in_date_issued) = 2014 then 1 else 0 end),
                AMTsum_jan2014=sum(case when datepart(mm, in_date_issued) <= 1 and 
                datepart(yyyy, in_date_issued) = 2014 then in_total else 0 end),
        AMTsum = sum(in_total),
        CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_Id
from (  
        select 
        distinct MasterOrderId,
                cl_Id 
            from CLOI_ClientOrderItems) as CLOI_ClientOrderItems 
        inner join IN_Invoices 
                on IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
group by CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
```

Comment: Do you want to have separate count?

Comment: yes NoOfInv having different numbers for particular clid

Comment: itsworkingand onemone AMTsum_jan2014 if i enter 5 i want to show that all month record i mean 1,2,3,4,5 months records

Comment: thank u now its showing by if i enter 3 month it showing wit previousmonth also and i want to add one more column is "remainingamount" columan need to add (PMTotal,FPreviousMonth ,SecondPreviousMonth)-(grand total) ans is remainingamount

Comment: here i am entering month number so its showing add all previous month record amount but if if pass month number itshould display all month name column nameand records

Comment: plsreply for that query

Comment: Post some sample data with expected result

Comment: you passed the month value 1 but you need jan , feb and mar as three different columns always?